# Regex trouble: how to get everything between the last two forward slashes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with a variable amount of backslashes. Now I want to collect only the part (letters) between the last two backslashes.

So if I have `/this/is/a/string/blablablablabla` I want to capture `string` and if I have `/this/is/a/longer/string/than/the/one/before/baba` I want to capture `before`.

What I have tried is:

```
 Regex.Match(myString, @"/(.*)/.*$").Groups[0].Value
```

but this captures everything between the first slash and also things after the last, and I want it to be between the one-before-last till the last. I am quite new to regexes and hope someone can help me out.

The last answer of [leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523496/leon) is`/([^/]*)/[^/]*$`, but this captures everything after the last / as well, and also includes the first `/`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us what you used, or what process you took so far?

Comment: @NewAmbition updated the question with my last try. :)

Comment: May be `(?<=/)(?<content>\w+)/(?!\w+/)` might help, I think there may be simpler expressions, but this one will work anyway. You can access the match from `Match.Groups["content"].Value`.

Comment: @Mathew thanks. Nice to know you can decide the capture group name with `<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one such pattern in your string, you can just use

```
/(\w+)/[^/]*$
```

Your data is in the first captured group.

`[^/]` will match anything BUT `/`, `\w` is short for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

---

**EDIT: Comment from OP**

`Groups[1]` was the first capturing group. So the answer in C# was:

```
answer = Regex.Match(myString, @"/(\w+)/[^/]*$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Let's go through it: `/` states we match the `/`, then we capture with `(\w+)` one or more words and we stop at a `/`. Then we do not match the slash itself with `[^/]` and we match everything till the end `(*$)`

Comment: Oh forgot to mention, the last backslash is not the end of the string.

Comment: We can put a `.*` in between?

Comment: Updated answer, you can use `[^/]+` instead of `\w+` but it can lead to multiline trouble. `.*` is generally avoided as much as possible, because it can easily lead to backtracking.

Comment: Thanks. It also captures the part after the first `/`. Of course I can split it, but I am sure there must be an improvement to the regex to get rid of that as well?

Comment: @user2609980: You data is in the captured group, not the match. See how you can access these in your language.

Comment: Yep! Thanks. `Groups[1]` was the first capturing group. So the answer in C# was: `answer = Regex.Match(myString, @"/(\w+)/[^/]*$").Groups[1].Value;`. Let's go through it: `/` states we match the `/`, then we capture with `(\w+)` one or more words and we stop at a `/`. Then we do not match the slash itself with `[^/]` and we match everything till the end `(*$)`. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to your question would be:

```
/([^/]*)/[^/]*$
```

Or, since your strings are pretty straightforward, you can avoid regexes altogether:

```
if (input.EndsWith("/"))
    return input.Split('/').Last();
else
    return input.Split('/').Reverse().Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: It does not necessarily end with a `/`. Your regex works, except for that if also captures the first `/` and captures everything after the last as well, which I do not want.

Comment: @user2609980 the regex I've provided contains a single catch group - this will contain exactly what you're looking for: `Regex.Match(...).Groups[1].Value` (`Groups[0]` is the whole expression). Otherwise please refer to my second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://regexr.com?38c43

(?:[a-z/]+)/([a-z]+)

Look in the first (and only) group, it'll have the last item.