# Find substring between slashes and replace that part in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, replace, substring

Using ASP.NET C#, I need to find and replace the word string1 between the last two slashes and replace with string2

**Example:**

```
string fullStr = "/this/is/string1/part";
string subStr = "function";
string finalStr = "/this/is/" + subStr + "/part";
```

Comment: What do you expect for this `/this/is/string1/part/string1/some` and this `/this/is/string1string1/part`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex trouble: how to get everything between the last two forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015096/regex-trouble-how-to-get-everything-between-the-last-two-forward-slashes)

Comment: The input string is the one in example and need to replace the word string1 with a variable that I have in my code @George

Comment: A solution could be using a regular expression, find the number of matches in the format /anystring/ , take the last and replace it by your new string

Comment: Try something looks like this: `var input = "/this/is/string1/part";
            var res = Regex.Replace(input, "/string1/", (item) => !item.NextMatch().Success ? "/string2/" : item.Value);`

Comment: the string1 is an unknown and I want to recognize it which will always be between the last two slashes @George Alexandria

Comment: @hsobhy I don't think it's complex enough to discuss much. See answer below. If that's not your expectation, then you have to update question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a regex solution:

```
string fullStr = "this/is/string1/part";
string subStr = "function";

var newstr = Regex.Replace(fullStr, @"/[^/]+/(?=[^/]+$)", m => "/" + subStr + "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel a need of regex here.

```
string fullStr = "/this/is/string1/part";
string subStr = "function";

string[] fullStrParts = fullStr.Split('/');
fullStrParts[fullStrParts.Length - 2] = subStr;

string finalStr = string.Join("/", fullStrParts);
```

Comment: It might be my language and the way I explain things, I need to find the string1 word which is not a static known part for me :)

Comment: So this logic replaces any word that is between last two `/`.

Comment: @hsobhy Do you want to find a some substring that you retrive from a some way? For example `public void GGG(string input, string substring, string replace) { var res = Regex.Replace(input, substring, (item) => !item.NextMatch().Success ? replace : item.Value);}`

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeAlexandria :)